# How do I build boost with new Visual Studio 2013 preview?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

When trying to build [Boost 1.54](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_54_0.html) for [Visual Studio 2013 Preview](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/2013-preview) (MSVC12) it warns:

> Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report
>   the results

and then fails with error:

> boost_1_54_0\boost/iterator/detail/facade_iterator_category.hpp(166) :
>   error C2039: 'assert_not_arg' : is not a member of 'boost::mpl'

And looks like old libs from MSVC11 are not compatible.

I really-really want to test new IDE/Compiler version and need boost. So, is it possible to use boost with new Visual Studio 2013 Preview?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

Possible solutions are:

1. Try build [Boost 1.53](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.53.0/): not too fresh, but for some strange reason it builds just fine.
2. If you *really-really* need Boost 1.54 (new Log library looks good :) ), try to apply [this](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/attachment/ticket/8750/vc12.patch) diff-patch to your Boost 1.54 distributive. It is best suited for revision 84920, but you can try any other too. Note that I am not author of this patch.
3. Try to get latest revision with [Subversion](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/): 
   `svn co  http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk boost-trunk`. For a time when you reading this, issue can be already fixed by contributors.

**EDIT: 26 aug 2013**

Looks like boost folks fixed these issues. Latest SVN revision `svn co  http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk boost-trunk` builds fine. Thanks to them!

**EDIT: 4 dec 2013**

Quote from TheArtTrooper comment:

> Boost 1.55.0 builds with the Visual Studio 2013 RTM without any
>   additional patches

Happy boosting!

Comment: Could you please explain why the following is needed in the patch: `#if _MSC_VER < 1800 && (_MSC_FULL_VER < 170051025 || !defined(BOOST_MSVC_ENABLE_2012_NOV_CTP))`

Comment: Here patch just adds check whether msvc version is lower than 1800 (Visual Studio 2013, aka "msvc12" ) and combines it with original checks. Original line checks if msvc not contains "update 3" or november's compiler update. If version checks fail, boost restricted  to not use some C++11 features, that orevious msvc versions not supports. Note that I am not autor of this patch (I will add this to the answer)

Comment: Ok I see. Actually, the original condition appears to be *stronger* than `_MSC_VER < 1800` addition, so it seems that patching this line was unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah, it's really redundant =)

Comment: I've compiled the 1_55_0 release tar ball with a minor patch: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20815896/85371

Answer (score 11):

If you use the auto-linking boost feature, you'll also need to patch boost/config/auto_link.hpp. I changed the file to:

```
    // vc10:
#    define BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET "vc100"

#  elif defined(BOOST_MSVC) && (BOOST_MSVC < 1800)

     // vc11:
#    define BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET "vc110"

#  elif defined(BOOST_MSVC)

     // vc12:
#    define BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET "vc120"

#  elif defined(__BORLANDC__)
```

Comment: Boost 1.55.0 builds with the Visual Studio 2013 RTM without any additional patches.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to build Boost 1.54 (and a project depending on it) thanks to [several patches provided by Lars Viklund](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Patch-bonanza-for-VS2013-Preview-support-td4649199.html). At the time of the writing, the first two of the patches were committed to the SVN - revision 85177.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 and Boost 1.54, update to Boost 1.57 fixed it.