# Cmake cannot find Boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am new to Cmake and boost libraries in C++. I am working on a project that needs boost and Cmake. I am using Cmake version 2.8.11, MS Visual Studio 2013 and Boost 1.54.0. When I try to configure from Cmake, it is giving the following error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1106     (message):
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

Boost version: 1.54.0

Boost include path: D:/boost_1_54_0

The following Boost libraries could not be found:

      boost_thread
      boost_system
      boost_log
      boost_log_setup
      boost_program_options

No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package)
```

I have seen quite a few questions related to mine and tried, but all went in vain. My Cmakelists.txt file looks like this:

```
################################
# Boost
################################
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON)
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS ON)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR D:/boost_1_54_0)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR D:/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib)
find_package( Boost 1.54.0 REQUIRED thread system log log_setup program_options)
find_package( Threads )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
```

The CMake output after setting Boost_DEBUG ON is as follows:

```
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:476 ]     _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:478 ]     Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:480 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = TRUE
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:482 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = 
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:484 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:486 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = 
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:538 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:540 ]   BOOST_ROOT = D:/boost_1_54_0
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:542 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = 
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:544 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = 
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:546 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:615 ] Include debugging info:
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:617 ]   _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS =    D:/boost_1_54_0/include;D:/boost_1_54_0;PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:619 ]   _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = boost-1_56_0;boost_1_56_0;boost/boost-1_56_0;boost/boost_1_56_0;boost-1_56;boost_1_56;boost/boost-1_56;boost/boost_1_56;boost-1_55_0;boost_1_55_0;boost/boost-1_55_0;boost/boost_1_55_0;boost-1_55;boost_1_55;boost/boost-1_55;boost/boost_1_55;boost-1_54_0;boost_1_54_0;boost/boost-1_54_0;boost/boost_1_54_0;boost-1_54;boost_1_54;boost/boost-1_54;boost/boost_1_54
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:639 ] location of version.hpp: D:/boost_1_54_0/boost/version.hpp
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:663 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.54.0
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:739 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -vc120
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:749 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:792 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:794 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -gd
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:842 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS = D:/boost_1_54_0/lib;D:/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib;D:/boost_1_54_0/lib;D:/boost_1_54_0/../lib;D:/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:930 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_thread-vc120-mt-1_54;libboost_thread-vc120-mt;libboost_thread-mt-1_54;libboost_thread-mt;libboost_thread;libboost_thread-vc120-mt-s-1_54;libboost_thread-vc120-mt-s;libboost_thread-mt-s-1_54;libboost_thread-mt-s
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:966 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_54;libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd;libboost_thread-mt-gd-1_54;libboost_thread-mt-gd;libboost_thread-mt;libboost_thread;libboost_thread-vc120-mt-s-gd-1_54;libboost_thread-vc120-mt-s-gd;libboost_thread-mt-s-gd-1_54;libboost_thread-mt-s-gd
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:930 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_system-vc120-mt-1_54;libboost_system-vc120-mt;libboost_system-mt-1_54;libboost_system-mt;libboost_system;libboost_system-vc120-mt-s-1_54;libboost_system-vc120-mt-s;libboost_system-mt-s-1_54;libboost_system-mt-s
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:966 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_54;libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd;libboost_system-mt-gd-1_54;libboost_system-mt-gd;libboost_system-mt;libboost_system;libboost_system-vc120-mt-s-gd-1_54;libboost_system-vc120-mt-s-gd;libboost_system-mt-s-gd-1_54;libboost_system-mt-s-gd
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:930 ] Searching for LOG_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_log-vc120-mt-1_54;libboost_log-vc120-mt;libboost_log-mt-1_54;libboost_log-mt;libboost_log;libboost_log-vc120-mt-s-1_54;libboost_log-vc120-mt-s;libboost_log-mt-s-1_54;libboost_log-mt-s
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:966 ] Searching for LOG_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_log-vc120-mt-gd-1_54;libboost_log-vc120-mt-gd;libboost_log-mt-gd-1_54;libboost_log-mt-gd;libboost_log-mt;libboost_log;libboost_log-vc120-mt-s-gd-1_54;libboost_log-vc120-mt-s-gd;libboost_log-mt-s-gd-1_54;libboost_log-mt-s-gd
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:930 ] Searching for LOG_SETUP_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_log_setup-vc120-mt-1_54;libboost_log_setup-vc120-mt;libboost_log_setup-mt-1_54;libboost_log_setup-mt;libboost_log_setup;libboost_log_setup-vc120-mt-s-1_54;libboost_log_setup-vc120-mt-s;libboost_log_setup-mt-s-1_54;libboost_log_setup-mt-s
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:966 ] Searching for LOG_SETUP_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_log_setup-vc120-mt-gd-1_54;libboost_log_setup-vc120-mt-gd;libboost_log_setup-mt-gd-1_54;libboost_log_setup-mt-gd;libboost_log_setup-mt;libboost_log_setup;libboost_log_setup-vc120-mt-s-gd-1_54;libboost_log_setup-vc120-mt-s-gd;libboost_log_setup-mt-s-gd-1_54;libboost_log_setup-mt-s-gd
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:930 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_program_options-vc120-mt-1_54;libboost_program_options-vc120-mt;libboost_program_options-mt-1_54;libboost_program_options-mt;libboost_program_options;libboost_program_options-vc120-mt-s-1_54;libboost_program_options-vc120-mt-s;libboost_program_options-mt-s-1_54;libboost_program_options-mt-s
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:966 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_program_options-vc120-mt-gd-1_54;libboost_program_options-vc120-mt-gd;libboost_program_options-mt-gd-1_54;libboost_program_options-mt-gd;libboost_program_options-mt;libboost_program_options;libboost_program_options-vc120-mt-s-gd-1_54;libboost_program_options-vc120-mt-s-gd;libboost_program_options-mt-s-gd-1_54;libboost_program_options-mt-s-gd
[ C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1017 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1106  (message):
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

Boost version: 1.54.0

Boost include path: D:/boost_1_54_0

The following Boost libraries could not be found:

      boost_thread
      boost_system
      boost_log
      boost_log_setup
      boost_program_options

No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:26 (find_package)
```

I have also tried writing set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON), but unfortunately it did not help. Suggestions are most welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have set it using `set(BOOST_ROOT D:/boost_1_54_0)` before calling find_package in CMakeLists.txt file, but got the same error.

Comment: If you add `set(Boost_DEBUG ON)` to your CMakeLists.txt, you should get a lot more debug output when you re-run.  If you still have the error after this, can you paste the CMake output into your question for us to see please?

Comment: How did you build boost 1.54.0?

Comment: @Vertexwahn: I built it from the MS visual studio command prompt by first executing the bootstrap command from inside the directory where boost is located and then using the bjam command.

Comment: @Fraser: I set the Boost_DEBUG ON and tried once again, but same error persists. I have added the CMake output in the question.

Comment: @user1382494 - Cool.  Now you need to look inside your boost folder and find the actual libraries.  Check their paths and names against the values CMake is telling you it's using.  So, for example, what's the full path to the boost thread library?

Answer (score 13):

Your configuration looks a bit weird and dirty. Especially things like:

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON)
```

It's not a C/C++ preprocessor definition! It's a CMake variable which is used to control how CMake will define the linkage stage of your project with Boost libraries.

If you properly compiled Boost and didn't mess up anything, then the directory structure usually looks like this:

```
<boost-dir>
  include
    boost
      accumulators
      ...
      aligned_storage.hpp
      ...
  lib
    libboost_atomic-mt-s.a
    ...
```

**NOTE:** The root directory of Boost, `<boost-dir>`, appears to be `D:/boost_1_54_0` in your case.

If in your case it does not look like above, then I'd suggest to rearrange it manually to the one above since, once again, this is how it should be.

When done, let's do some CMake configuration. I suggest to keep things simple and clean in the first place, and obey the CMake conventions. Test the following:

```
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR D:/boost_1_54_0/include)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR D:/boost_1_54_0/lib)
```

**NOTE:** You can find thorough description of both of these variables at the top of `FindBoost.cmake`.

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
```

**NOTE:** This is how you enforce static linkage by setting the CMake variable properly, but not like you did by setting a non-existent C/C++ preprocessor definition.

```
find_package(Boost
             1.54.0
             COMPONENTS thread
                        system
                        log
                        log_setup
                        program_options
             REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(<target_name> ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

**NOTE:** Instead of `<target_name>`, put the name of the target that you wish to build (executable, static/shared library, etc.).

Comment: Since the Op builds under VS, his library files probably ended up under `stage` instead of `lib`. That being said, setting anything apart from `BOOST_ROOT` yourself inside CMake is already more or less asking for trouble.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: Of course it is. But I'm giving him a suggestion how to test whether his setup is supposed to work at all. Setting paths explicitly inside `CMakeLists.txt` is indeed against general recommendations and I'll drop a note about it and edit my answer with better option as soon as the author confirms that at least this works for him. Even setting `BOOST_ROOT` is bad practice by the way. All these path-hint variables should be set during the invocation of CMake because they depend exclusively on the current environment.

Comment: @Haroogan: Thank you very much for the detailed reply. Currently I had to format my machine and am facing some troubles regarding few tasks. I will get back to this as soon as I fix that thing. Thanks once again for your patience.

Comment: @Haroogan: I cleaned up my CmakeLists.txt file and performed the steps as suggested by you. But, still the same error persists. I, then uninstalled MS Visual Studio 2013 and installed MS Visual Studio 2012 and tried once again. Still the error persists. Then, I installed Boost 1.54.0 and Cmake in Ubuntu and it's working perfectly fine in Ubuntu. Hence, I am working on it in Ubuntu now to save time.

Comment: Have you tried both `set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR D:/boost_1_54_0/lib)` and `set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR D:/boost_1_54_0/lib/stage)`? Furthermore, I see that you are using VS 2013, and debugging shows that CMake is not searching for `*-vc130-*` libraries, it only searches for `*-vc120-*`. This could very much be the reason. Do you have Boost libraries for VS 12 or VS 13?

Comment: Yes I had tried both the paths. Yes, the VS 13 was giving many problems, so I tried with VS 12 too, but nothing changed. Nevertheless, in Ubuntu, everything is working fine now.

Comment: In my case, two problems were preventing the build. The directory structure was pretty weird and I hadn't specified set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON) in cmakelists.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Boost 1.54.0 cannot be built with VS2013 without applying some patches. See also here [How do I build boost with new Visual Studio 2013 preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440810/how-do-i-build-boost-with-new-visual-studio-2013-preview)

If you build it correctly, everything else should work.

Answer (score -3):

In the lib folder, rename:
`libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_49.lib` to `boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_49.lib`
`libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.lib` to `boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_49.lib`
... and so on. Then they can be found.