# Error C2338: !boost::is_integral<T>::value with boost

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to use boost in oder to calculate a factorial. I don't know why, but VS2013 show me a compiling error.

Anyone have some ideas please ?

```
int nLgCombi = 12;
std::vector<std::string>   NbrToPlay;
...
int ne = NbrToPlay.size();
int calcnc = boost::math::factorial<int>(ne + 1) / boost::math::factorial<int>(nLgCombi);
```

**Error message :**

Erreur  1   error C2338: !boost::is_integral::value  d:\users\XXXXXX\downloads\boost_1_55_0b1\boost_1_55_0b1\boost\math\special_functions\factorials.hpp 32  1   APPS

EDIT :

**Code replace int by double:**

```
double dcalcnc = boost::math::factorial<double>(ne +1) / boost::math::factorial<double>(nLgCombi);
```

**Error message :**

Erreur  1   error C2039: 'assert_not_arg' : n'est pas membre de 'boost::mpl'    d:\users\XXXXX\downloads\boost_1_55_0b1\boost_1_55_0b1\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\plain\arg.hpp    45  1

Erreur  2   error C3861: 'assert_not_arg' : identificateur introuvable  d:\users\XXXXX\downloads\boost_1_55_0b1\boost_1_55_0b1\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\plain\arg.hpp    45  1

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Nixeus

Comment: Post the complete error message, please. It includes information on what `T` is in the case when it fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Boost documentation about factorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/factorials/sf_factorial.html) :

```
 BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(!boost::is_integral<T>::value); 
 // factorial<unsigned int>(n) is not implemented 
 // because it would overflow integral type T for too small n 
 // to be useful. Use instead a floating-point type, 
 // and convert to an unsigned type if essential, for example: 
 // unsigned int nfac = static_cast<unsigned int>(factorial<double>(n)); 
 // See factorial documentation for more detail.
```

The factorial version for `int` and `unsigned int` are not yet implemented because even for small values it would lead to an overflow.

For example, the factorial of 13 is 6227020800, which exceeds the maximum limit of an `unsigned int` (4294967295 if ints are 4 bytes long).

You must use `double` or `float` to calculate the factorial.

Comment: Hello, you're right, i saw this a few minutes ago ! I modifty my code in order to deal with double but i have another error message. Erreur 1 error C2039: 'assert_not_arg' : n'est pas membre de 'boost::mpl' d:\users\XXXXX\downloads\boost_1_55_0b1\boost_1_55_0b1\boost\mpl\aux_\preprocessed\plain\arg.hpp

Comment: It seems that Visual Studio is not compatible with that certain feature according to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440810/how-do-i-build-boost-with-new-visual-studio-2013-preview

Comment: Yes, i saw this too, using boost 1.53,and, it's ok !