# bootstrap boost with Visual Studio 2013 hangs

Tags: visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2013

I want to build Boost 1_54_0 under Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2013.  I opened a VS 2013 command prompt, cd'd into the boost_1_54_0 directory, and said `bootstrap`.  I saw a message "Building Boost.Build engine", and then no indication of progress for hours.  I couldn't find any way to abort the process, so I rebooted.  Then I opened bootstrap.log, and the last thing in there is this:

C:\Code\boost_1_54_0_full\boost_1_54_0\tools\build\v2\engine>.\bootstrap\jam0 -f build.jam --toolset=vc10 "--toolset-root=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools....\VC\ "  clean

That "Visual Studio 10.0" means it's actually trying to compile using the Visual Studio 2010 tools rather than 2013, right?

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: for the record, I had 2 problems.  One was the problem with Boost that was fixed by using the version from svn.  The other was that VS 2013 provides 3 command prompt shortcuts:

1. Developer Command Prompt for VS2013
2. VS2013 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt
3. VS2013 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt

Since I was trying to build 32-bit libraries, something with "x64" in the name seemed like the least logical choice to try, but it turned out to be the only one that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Boost 1.54 and even 1.55 is not compatible with VS 2013 because VS was released *after* these Boost releases. You can take a compatible version at the Boost SVN.

See also the discussion here: [How do I build boost with new Visual Studio 2013 preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440810/how-do-i-build-boost-with-new-visual-studio-2013-preview/17440811#17440811)

Comment: I downloaded the current version by svn, but it still just sits there after saying "Building Boost.Build engine".  After rebooting, the log does indicate that it was using the VS2013 compiler this time.

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong. Boost suggest to file an issue with them attaching the log file. I suspect something is wrong with your PATH. Why would bootstrap pick up VS 2010 when you started from VS-2013 command prompt? BTW, it is likely you can interrupt bootstrap with Ctrl-Z. Good luck!

Comment: I've added the final resolution to my question.  By the way Ctrl-Z did not work, nor did Ctrl-C.

Comment: Thank you, your finding about 3 command prompt shortcuts is really helpful.