# Build boost on visual studio 2013 XP toolset

Tags: c++, boost, build, windows-xp, visual-studio-2013

I need to build boost (1.55) with VS2013, but the regular toolset (toolset=msvc-12.0) doesn't work on XP. There is a different toolset for XP (which you can change in VS itself).

Does anyone know the toolset string I need to use in order to compile boost for XP using msvc-12.0 ?

EDIT: I'm using b2.exe

Thanks You!

Comment: if you do not need extra stuff in your build, you could download the binaries [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/).

Comment: @itwasntpete - I checked it out, but I only saw msvc12x86 and x64, nothing specific for XP...

Comment: sorry, my link was wrong. i changed it :)

Comment: the downloaded version i use on visual studio 2013 and compiled my project with **Platform Toolset** v120_xp. and it works without any doubt.

Comment: @itwasntpete, I'm trying to compile with b2.exe

Comment: @itwasntpete Except that boost serialization isn't there. See this answer **[Building boost with Visual Studio 2013 (Express)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813138/building-boost-with-visual-studio-2013-express/20815896#20815896)**. This contains the patches needed to compile on MSVC12, perhaps it will help with the XP toolchain too

Comment: @sehe - its building fine. I'm just trying to build it with XP toolset

Comment: @TCS lol - this I've heard before. [/are you sure/? It's kinda easy to miss, unless you *needed* Boost serialization :{](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813138/building-boost-with-visual-studio-2013-express/20815896#comment31212394_20815896). Just a headsup. If you don't need it, just ignore the comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this link: https://web.archive.org/web/20130208113614/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/10357555.aspx

original link (dead): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/10357555.aspx

It explains how to compile in command line using cl.exe and choose XP toolset.

When compiling boost, before starting the build itself using b2.exe, insert all required parameters in order to choose 120_xp toolset.

Comment: can you provide some detail? I want to target v140_xp but no matter what I put for b2 toolset=xxx it says "rule "xxx.init" unknown in module "toolset"

Answer (score 0):

put for b2.ex --toolset=msvc-12.0_xp