# How do I compile boost 1.55.0 through win7 (32bit) for Code Blocks 13.12?

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, boost, codeblocks

Iv'e been at it for hours now and can't find a straight answer anywhere. After unpacking the boost zip contents into the directory (placed it in C:\Program Files\boost_1_55_0), I started up the command prompt and tried compiling the batch (bootsrap.bat), as instructed. Failed.

The message returns:
    Building Boost.Build engine
    'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch
    file.
    Failed to build Boost.Build engine.
    Please consult bootstrap.log for further diagnostics.

The bootstrap.log reads:

```
   ###
   ### Using 'msvc' toolset.
   ###

   C:\Program Files\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine>if exist bootstrap rd /S /Q                   
   bootstrap 
   C:\Program Files\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine>md bootstrap 
   C:\Program Files\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine>cl /nologo /GZ /Zi /MLd      
   /Fobootstrap/
   /Fdbootstrap/ -DNT -DYYDEBUG kernel32.lib advapi32.lib user32.lib    
   /Febootstrap\jam0
   command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c execcmd.c execnt.c filent.c frames.c 
   function.c
   glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c  
   object.c
   option.c output.c parse.c pathnt.c pathsys.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c 
   subst.c
   timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c md5.c class.c cwd.c 
   w32_getreg.c
   native.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c  
   modules/sequence.c modules/order.c
```

Any ideas????
Thank you, in advance, for your time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

Each compiler may use a different format for its static library file. It depends on which compiler you use in your CodeBlocks. By default, boost building commands uses VC toolset .

- MinGW: Run your building commands for MinGW. check this: [Building Boost 1.52 with MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256788/building-boost-1-52-with-mingw). Though it's for 1.52, the commands are the same.

  ```
  bootstrap.bat mingw    
  b2 toolset=gcc
  ```
- VC: You should set environment variables of Visual Studio before running the commands. After Visual Studio installation, "Developer Command Prompt" is provided with all these environment variables. Check this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-from-the-command-prompt.

Comment: For the VC way of working: you'll need a patch. See [Building boost with Visual Studio 2013 (Express)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20815896/85371)