# Building boost 1.55 with Visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: serialization, boost, express, visual-studio-2013

Well, this question was already raised a while ago: ["Building boost with Visual Studio 2013 (Express)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813138/building-boost-with-visual-studio-2013-express).

It seems the questioner was able to do the job. So I followed the instructions by patching the according files, but I'm still not able to compile the serialization library (need for serialization support is the reason why I tried to compile boost myself)

What else could be necessary to get it compiled?

Thanks for any response in advance!

Comment: Can you post the errors you are observing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is more or less the start of the build.log; in total there are 8 Targets skipped:


`output deleted - I found a way to compile boost's serialization library - see below`

Comment: Next time don't put replies to comments in answers. Insead you edit your question and add requested data. It will be easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: thanks for your hint - will respect this next time. If someone wants to compile boost 1.55 with serialization Support for VC2013, here is what you need to do: apply this patch: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9410 and this one: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9196 - then it works

Answer (score 2):

Modify these files :
https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/attachment/ticket/9410/config_decltype_n3276_new.patch

Then 
Add `#include <algorithm>` to the four files
`libs\serialization\src\basic_text_*primitive.cpp`

Comment: This helped a lot! TYVM! Why the heck this isn't the accepted answer confuses me...