# Include the tlhelp32 header file

Tags: c++, header-files

I need to include the `tlhelp32.h` header file from the Tool Help Library but it always comes up with the following error:

> error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tlhelp32.h': No such file or
>   directory

I did a little bit of research and tried to first include the `windows.h` header file but this did not change anything.

I'm coding in C++ using Visual Studio 2013 Express with Windows 10 1709. Do I have to download anything else?

Comment: You'll need to add the path where the header resides to your include path in the visual studio project.

Comment: So where is this header file usually located? I dont have it / cant find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789969/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-xyz-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Actually, check out the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878267/how-to-build-boost-1-55-with-visual-studio-2013?r=SearchResults

Comment: You are missing too much context. Please state the platform and show the compile command and the error. I believe Tool Help library library was removed from some versions of Windows and apps. For example, it is not available in UWP apps. Instead, you have to build a Desktop app. Also see [Support for "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot" Api in <TlHelp32.h> Windows Runtime Componenet (Universal Windows 10) project](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1dc3792b-1639-4829-8aab-da75c25ac143/uwpccxsupport-for-quotcreatetoolhelp32snapshotquot-api-in-lttlhelp32hgt-windows?forum=wpdevelop) on MSDN.