# What's happening of boost 1.56 and boost 1.57?

Tags: c++, boost

As we can see in Boost Roadmap site(https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/roadmap), boost 1.56 was scheduled release in 2/3/2014, which is 4 months late, and boost 1.57 was scheduled release in 5/5/2014, which is 3 weeks late. And the progress doesn't even change in last few days. 
What's happening in boost 1.56 & 1.57?

Comment: No idea if this is true, but I remember reading somewhere the problem is they migrated from svn to git, and are having quite a few problems with the code base related to that change.

Comment: See also http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2014/05/212954.php

Comment: @Nemo, Ooh, seems release might not be too far away then.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about news

Comment: For some code bases this is a serious problem since VS2013 does not work with Boost 1.55.0 and we need Boost 1.56!

Comment: @Vertexwahn or you can just fix it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20815896/85371