# Build Boost 1.63

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, boost

I am trying to build boost 1.63 with msvc 15.8.2. So I did everything I do normally, I opened the Development Cmd and then I run the bootstrap.bat and run the command

```
.\b2
```

And also after reading questions related to it I also executed everything on x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017 and ran the command

```
b2 toolset=msvc-14.0 address-model=64
```

For some reason I got the same error in both the cases:

```
C:/Coding/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/tools\msvc.jam:834: in generate-setup-cmd
    *** argument error
    * rule maybe-rewrite-setup ( toolset : setup-script : setup-options : version : rewrite-setup ? )
    * called with: ( msvc :  :  : default :  )
    * missing argument setup-script
C:/Coding/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/tools\msvc.jam:746:see definition of rule 'maybe-rewrite-setup' being called
C:/Coding/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/tools\msvc.jam:1076: in configure-really
C:/Coding/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/tools\msvc.jam:201: in configure
C:/Coding/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/tools\msvc.jam:153: in msvc.init
C:/Coding/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/build\toolset.jam:43: in toolset.using
C:/Coding/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:1052: in using
    project-config.jam:3: in modules.load
C:/Coding/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:249: in load-config
C:/Coding/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:412: in load-configuration-files
C:/Coding/boost_1_63_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:524: in load
C:\Coding\boost_1_63_0\tools\build\src/kernel\modules.jam:295: in import
C:\Coding\boost_1_63_0\tools\build\src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
C:\Coding\boost_1_63_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

My project-config.jam file is below

```
import option ; 

using msvc ; 

option.set keep-going : false ;
```

I am not familiar with boost so hoping that one of you could tell me how to fix the problem.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 is `msvc-15`, but you are giving `msvc-14.0` to `b2`. You don't usually need to pass any parameters `b2`, or, god save, edit/create any `.jam` files. In this case it should pick the most appropriate version of MSVC automatically. Exception would be if you use [pre-release versions of compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440810/how-do-i-build-boost-with-new-visual-studio-2013-preview/17440811#17440811) etc. What happens if you remove start over and simply run `bootstrap` and `b2`? Also, latest boost version is 1.65, so I'd invite you to upgrade.

Comment: I am getting the same error while implementing `b2`. I can try with version 1.65.

Comment: Another question is whether your compiler is functional. What happens if you run `cl`? Also, I think you are not posting the error message in it's entirety. There should be more.

Comment: When I run `cl` a command prompt pops and closes with a second or two. I am posting all the errors that I encounter.

Comment: I just did all the steps with 1.65 version and the `.\b2` file is updating some files. Does that happen generally? After updating all the target files will it run?